# TypeError .map() is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, jsx

Newbie question here from someone who's getting started with `React`.

I have a `function` that passes two props:

```
function Turn(author, books) {
  return (<div className="row turn" style={{backgroundColor: "white"}}>
      <div className="col-4 offset-1">
        <img src ={author.imageUrl} className="authorimage" alt="Author"></img>
      </div>
      <div className="col-6">
        {books.map((title) => <p>{title}</p>)}
      </div>
    </div>);
}
```

In a separate `JS` file within the same folder, I have the following:

```
const authors = [
  {
    name: 'Mark Twain',
    imageUrl: 'images/authors/marktwain.jpg',
    imageSource: 'Wikimedia Commons',
    books: ['The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn']
  }
];

const state = {
  turnData: {
    author: authors[0],
    books: authors[0].books
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthorQuiz {...state} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`Turn` is rendered as part of the `AuthorQuiz` function passing the `turnData` state as props as follows:

```
function AuthorQuiz({turnData}) {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <Hero/>
      <Turn {...turnData}/>
      <Continue/>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then running this on `localhost`, I get:

[image]

Does this have something to do with how `books` is declared? Hovering over `books` in my state variable it's shown as a `string[]`. Any help to unblock this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How the `Turn` component is rendered? Which argument expect `AuthorQuiz` ?

Comment: The error means that the `books` being passed into the `Turn` component is not an array. You might try logging it to the console to get a better idea of what's actually being passed in. You haven't shown us how `books` makes its way from the code in the bottom to the `Turn` component, so there's not enough information here to tell you where you've gone wrong.

Comment: do a console.log  before return of Turn method and see what this method is receiving:
```function Turn(author, books) { console.log({author, books}); ```

Comment: @JLRishe Does my edit of the post help clarify? How do I add a console log into the `Turn` function to see what's being passed?

Comment: @Javier Add `console.log(books);` after the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
function Turn(author, books) {
```

with

```
function Turn({ author, books }) {
```

It's a props object, not separate arguments.